# Fixing OpenCV Python stream ingestion

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to break a video down into frames, draw some boxes and labels on the frames, and then feed them into a RedisImageStream, like this:

```
   def get_last(self):
        ''' Gets latest from camera and model '''
        p = self.conn.pipeline()
        p.xrevrange(self.camera, count=1)  # Latest frame
        p.xrevrange(self.boxes, count=1)   # Latest boxes
        cmsg, bmsg = p.execute()
        if cmsg:
            last_id = cmsg[0][0].decode('utf-8')
            label = f'{self.camera}:{last_id}'
            data = io.BytesIO(cmsg[0][1][self.field])
            img = Image.open(data)
            if bmsg:
                boxes = np.fromstring(bmsg[0][1]['boxes'.encode('utf-8')][1:-1], sep=',')
                label += ' people: {}'.format(bmsg[0][1]['people'.encode('utf-8')].decode('utf-8'))
                for box in range(int(bmsg[0][1]['people'.encode('utf-8')])):  # Draw boxes
                    x1 = boxes[box*4]
                    y1 = boxes[box*4+1]
                    x2 = boxes[box*4+2]
                    y2 = boxes[box*4+3]
                    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
                    draw.rectangle(((x1, y1), (x2, y2)), width=5, outline='red')
            arr = np.array(img)
            arr = cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            cv2.putText(arr, label, (10, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            ret, img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', arr)
            return img.tobytes()
```

At this point, I should be getting bytes. The output of get_last feeds into this generator:

```
def gen(stream):
    while True:
        try:
            frame = stream.get_last()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Pragma-directive: no-cache\r\n'
                b'Cache-directive: no-cache\r\n'
                b'Cache-control: no-cache\r\n'
                b'Pragma: no-cache\r\n'
                b'Expires: 0\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
        except Exception as exception:
            # Output unexpected Exceptions.
            logging.error("Error occurred", exc_info=True)
```

The output of the generator should go into a return stream on an HTTP route:

```
@app.route('/video')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(RedisImageStream(conn, args)),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Instead, this throws an error per frame:

```
in gen
b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes
```

How should I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `get_last()` you have

```
 if cmsg:
      # ... code ...
      return frame
```

but you don't have

```
 else:
      # ... code ...
      return frame
```

so sometimes it can runs `return one` at the end of this function

and then `frame = stream.get_last()` may get `frame = None`

You should check it before sending frame

```
    frame = stream.get_last()
    #if frame is not None:
    if frame:
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Pragma-directive: no-cache\r\n'
            b'Cache-directive: no-cache\r\n'
            b'Cache-control: no-cache\r\n'
            b'Pragma: no-cache\r\n'
            b'Expires: 0\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

Sometimes camera may need time for warm up (ie. probably in Raspberry Pi) and then it may send `None` instead of frame - and you have to check `if frame is not None`.

---

**As for debuging.**

I saw problem with `None` in `frame`  many times so already knew where to search problem but if you want to debug it then you could use `print()` to check values in variable and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"`.

First you should check `print(frame, type(frame))` before line which gives error. I expect you get `None`. Because you get `frame` from `get_last()` so next you should use `print()` inside `get_frame()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. And if you would put `print("I am inside 'if'")` inside `if cmsg:` then you shouldn't see this text on screen. And this should give you clue where is problem. You could check `print(cmsg, type(cmsg))` to see what you get in this variable. Because you get this value from `p.execute()` then you should check code in `p.execute()` or `p`. And this way you could move back in code until you place which starts this problem.